# Oracle Forms Round Corners Button

Tags: oracle, button, oracleforms

I am inserting a push button in oracle form builder but I want to customize its corners in round shape just like below mentioned image.

Any help willl be highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've never done that (didn't have to & I'm quite happy with buttons as they are), but - it seems that you'll have to use PJC (Pluggable Java Components) and Java Beans. These are terms you should be searching for; one resource is [A non rectangular button's PJC](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-16690542.html); see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you would need to create a Plugable Java Component (PJC) if you want round ended buttons.  The demos that Oracle used to provide included an example of such a PJC, however they are no longer available.  So some Google searching might be needed if you want to find them.

The good news is that there are plans to introduce this functionality as a feature in a future release.  If added to the product, you would no longer need to use a PJC.  Unfortunately, the release date of that version cannot be shared at this time.  For the latest information about Oracle Forms, refer to:

https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/forms/forms.html